# Why a useful comment got deleted while the non-useful one are kept?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

I commented on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55613436/8620333) but after few minutes my comment got deleted. I am aware that it's a common situation to delete *no longer needed* comments but I disagree with this deletion because I think my comment is useful and can be needed while all the others are *no longer needed*.

---

**To add some context**

The OP asked a question where he want to understand the *"why"* of an issue and he was not looking for a way to fix it as he already know how to.

I have closed the question as duplicate and commented to add **another similar** fix to the same issue. That comment got deleted later and in my opinion it should be kept because it can be helpful for future readers who don't need (or don't want) to understand what is happening and they are simply looking for a quick fix.

I know that this deletion isn't a big issue and that I can add the comment again but I simply want to understand why it got deleted too fast? especially that all the others are really not needed and should be deleted.

The comment was:

> adding position:relative to the image also fix the issue

**UPDATE**

My comment is different from the information already present in the question that's why I added my comment. I already saw this:

> Adding `position:relative` to `.caption` solves the problem,

I was suggesting to add position:relative to the image which is another way to fix the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

I wasn't the moderator who handled this, but I think I understand why this comment was deleted. The sequence of events as I see it was that the question was first asked, then 9 minutes later they edited it to say

> Adding `position:relative` to `.caption` solves the problem, but does not answer the question.

You suggested the potential duplicate four minutes after that, and then left the comment

> position:relative to img also fix the issue

three minutes after the close vote.

Your comment came after the question had been edited to include the recognition of this, and was flagged as "no longer needed". I probably would have deleted this, too, given that it restates something that was already indicated in the question before the comment was left.

The other comments that referred to this one should have been cleaned up at the time, so I've gone ahead and done so. They might not have been as visible from the comment flag interface.

Comment: `.caption` isn't the image, I saw this information in the question ... my comment is to add the position to the image element not the text element (this is why I added the comment)

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Your comment is a little hard to parse, and multiple people (including myself) missed that you were trying to say that adding this to the image, not just `.caption`, would also solve the problem. Something that called this out explicitly, preferably in a full sentence, probably would not have been flagged and removed. In any case, it sounds like fixing the issue was independent of understanding why this was happening, and the duplicate you pointed to seemed to satisfy that. They were happy with your contribution there, so things worked out well overall.

Comment: @TemaniAfif incorrect comment flag VS moderator humanity. Round 1: Fight! Incorrect comment flag wins. Flawless victory.

Comment: I know at the end this isn't a big deal but I was really surprised by the fast deletion as I was still in the page following the comments. If it was done later I would probably never notice this. I also don't think that a  *full clear sentence* is needed because it's a comment after all and what I said (IMHO) should be clear to anyone reading the question and looking at the code. The comment *alone* can never be clear (by the way, I have no idea how comments are seen in the backend by Moderators)

Comment: I always suspected that comment flags were stealing our humanity. Now we have proof, eh @Gimby?